# Make api that runs commands on linux server

Tags: php, linux, api, server

Would it be possible to make an API that sends linux commands to the server?

I would be looking for something that looks like this

```
// http://localhost/command=netstat
<?php
$command = $_GET['command'];

// Sends server $command
?>
```

Comment: I hope that you intend to have a white list of commands and attributes, or you have just opened up for anyone to take over your server? Suggestion for next time, try google before posting a question (will go faster). Something like "php run linux command" would give you _many_ links about this, including the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

Comment: yes, it is possible - quite easy, too. but you really really **should not do that** unless you *absolutely* know what you are doing. otherwise, it will be a matter of hours, or even minutes, before your server is **compromised**, because that is insecurity by design.

Comment: I wrote a package [`Flask-shell2http`](https://github.com/Eshaan7/Flask-Shell2HTTP) to achieve this with full control using python code.

Answer (score 0):

exec is used to execute external program.

```
string exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Following is an example code; I did this to use ffmpeg to convert video in php.

```
$a = exec('C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i 56c6ed0e49fe0.qt -strict -2 out22.mp4');
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: _Suggestion:_ You might want to mention the extreme security threat this poses when used together with user inputs. Allowing any command and attributes/params to be passed (together with improper escaping etc), it won't take long until th OP has lost control of the server.

Comment: Then just add security at api level. The command I sent, will work on local server so no security threat.

Comment: There are many ways you can add security, but the risk should be mentioned in the answer, since many people just read the answers and then copy/paste the code.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson 100% Agreed :) exec can perform many operations at server so you can not open it for all users to do anything wrong. Magnus's suggestion is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

shell2http can do that.
https://github.com/msoap/shell2http

So on the host run

```
shell2http -port 8080 /diskspace "df -h"
```

And then remotely from a browser or using `curl` run

```
# assuming host IP is 1.2.3.4
http://1.2.3.4:8080/diskspace
```

To be persistent on startup I supposed you could run a script.